# Polars DataFrame pivot table having List[str] as a dtype

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

```
data = {"error":[["x","z"],None,["x","z"],None],
          "X" : ["x","p","x","p"],
          "Y" : ["y","q","y","q"],
          "Z": ["z","r","z","r"],
          "time": ["Jan","Jan","Feb","Feb"],
          "value": [10,20,15,19]}
```

dataframe of data

[image]

```
poldf = pl.DataFrame(data)
pol_piv = poldf.pivot(values="value",columns="time",index=["X","Y","Z","error"])
```

The **pivot** function throwing error that it doesn't support List[str]
I tried this in pandas as well but no succuss.

Comment: Why did you tag this with [pandas]? If you want to ask about both libraries, the title should reflect that. It'd also help to ask an actual question; see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can [`.cast()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cast.html#polars.Expr.cast) to `List[cat]` before pivoting.

```py
(df.with_columns(pl.col("error").cast(pl.List(pl.Categorical)))
   .pivot(values="value", columns="time", index=["X","Y","Z","error"])
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 6)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ X   ┆ Y   ┆ Z   ┆ error      ┆ Jan ┆ Feb │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---        ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str ┆ str ┆ list[cat]  ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ z   ┆ ["x", "z"] ┆ 10  ┆ 15  │
│ p   ┆ q   ┆ r   ┆ null       ┆ 20  ┆ 19  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────────┴─────┴─────┘
```